# Invalid model formula error for tidyr 0.4.0

Tags: r, tidyr, project-template

I'm getting the message `Error: invalid model formula in ExtractVars` while trying to fit linear models using tidyr version 0.4.0. I have run this exact code without error in a previous session, but have changed some library info, so I'm wondering if that is perhaps the issue.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

# create one dataframe for each country
by_country <- gapminder %>%
  group_by(continent, country) %>%
  nest()

# fit a linear model to each country with purrr, save as new var 'model'
by_country <- by_country %>% 
  mutate(model = purrr::map(data, ~ lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = .)))
```

Here's my session info:

> R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>    [1] dplyr_0.4.3         broom_0.4.0         purrr_0.2.0         tidyr_0.4.0         gapminder_0.2.0     lubridate_1.3.3
>    [7] stringr_1.0.0       ggplot2_1.0.1       plyr_1.8.3          reshape_0.8.5       ProjectTemplate_0.6
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-43      mnormt_1.5-3     munsell_0.4.2    lattice_0.20-33  colorspace_1.2-6 R6_2.1.2
>    [9] tools_3.2.2      parallel_3.2.2   grid_3.2.2       nlme_3.1-121     gtable_0.1.2     psych_1.5.8      DBI_0.3.1        lazyeval_0.1.10 
>   [17] digest_0.6.8     assertthat_0.1   reshape2_1.4.1   memoise_1.0.0    labeling_0.3     stringi_1.0-1    scales_0.3.0     proto_0.3-10

I'm using ProjectTemplate, which automatically loads these libraries before running the above code (I think): `reshape`, `plyr`, `ggplot2`, `stringr`, `lubridate`, `gapminder`, `tidyr`, `purrr`, `broom`, `dplyr`. I realize there is some duplication, but don't think it would cause the code not to run? Any insight is super appreciated!

Comment: Works for me. It's the example from the RStudio blog? Try restarting and just loading the necessary packages only...

Comment: @StephenHenderson Exactly, the example from the RStudio blog. I tried restarting and loading only `projecttemplate`, `ggplot2`, `lubridate`, `gapminder`, `tidyr`, `purrr`, `broom`, and `dplyr` (in that order), but still get the same error.

Comment: try without `projecttemplate` and maybe not `purrr` as you are importing `purrr::map` if it still doesn't work ... maybe file a bug report.

Comment: @HubertL hmm... the `nest()` statement works fine for me, I just run into issues in the next step when trying to build the models. Are you using version 0.4.0 of `tidyr`?

Comment: @StephenHenderson okay, loaded libraries without `projecttemplate`. tried in this order: `gapminder`, `dplyr`, `magrittr`, `tidyr`, `ggplot2`, `purrr`, `broom`, and it works. When tried in this order `ggplot2`, `lubridate`, `gapminder`, `tidyr`, `purrr`, `broom`, `dplyr`, I get the original error. I don't see any masked objects from the version that produces the error that seem related.

Comment: OK, it works for me. It's their example. If you are all updated and you're sure you haven't any odd typo then file a bug report.

Comment: @HubertL You will need 0.4 as shown here: http://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/

Comment: Right, it works well with 0.4.1

Comment: @StephenHenderson do both versions of loading in the libraries work for you, or just the first? Also, RE: filing a bug report, would it fall under purrr instead of tidyr? I've never filed one before.

Comment: @HubertL Thanks for trying it out. I think it's an issue of the order I'm loading libraries. If you load the libraries in this order: `ggplot2`, `lubridate`, `gapminder`, `tidyr`, `purrr`, `broom`, `dplyr`, does the rest of the code work for you?

Comment: Yes I reproduce when I load in that order, I get a warning `Attachement du package : ‘dplyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    order_by

The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:

    intersect, setdiff, union

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union`

Comment: But it works if I don't load `lubridate`

Comment: @StephenHenderson This seems to be a bug, If I load `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `purrr` and run `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest() %>% mutate(mode = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .)))` it works fine, if I load `ggplot2` as well, I get a very similar error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : invalid term in model formula`